# Render attribute will create a component again or update the model only?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I am trying below code

```
public String collapseTreeById(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
     String treeId = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("treeId");
     UITree tree = (UITree)event.getComponent().findComponent(treeId);
     tree.getParent().getChildren().clear();

     return null;
 }
```

Here you can check i already remove all the children of the component and this method called like this

```
<a4j:commandLink actionListener="#{inventoriesBean.collapseTreeById}"
                             value="collapse" render="treeServType">
 <f:param value="treeServType" name="treeId" />
 </a4j:commandLink>
```

and also added `render` but still i am seeing tree is in same state(No change from previous state) and not created again . If render not creating a component again and updating model value then even tree state should be change? Its also not happening.

Why?

Comment: What exactly is represented by the `a4j` namespace?

Comment: Rich-faces component

Comment: I don't see any `render` attribute for the `a4j:commandLink` (https://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/tlddoc/a4j/commandLink.html)

Comment: This is the nth time that someone removes the tag from the title of your question (we already have a whole separate section for tags which is so much more useful). Can you please take this as a hint to not do that anymore in your future questions? Thank you.

Comment: It was `reRender` in old now Jboss4 its call `render`

Comment: ok @BalusC from onwards i will not add tag in question title

Answer (score 0):

Render generates pieces of HTML and sends them to the client, since you've removed the tree it doesn't send back anything. If you want it to work you have to wrap the tree in another component and rerender that component.

On the other hand emptying the list of children doesn't really do anything (and you shouldn't do it), the component tree is recreated with each request.

Comment: Thanks but in my case Tree is showing in same condition it mean if i expand some branch after click button render again now that expand node +/- sign gone and also no child there see for more info https://developer.jboss.org/message/936118#936118